# Windows Store App - Installer location (Recommendations for hosting site)

Tags: windows-store

I have come across this while Creating an app package for the Microsoft Store while using Visual Studio to create the app package when I right-click on the project file and Publish>Create App Packages...

[image]

Where can I host this file for the installer location URL, UNC path of file share location?

Can anyone recommend a good hosting site?

Comment: A UNC path is a path to a file on your own computer.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've put `https://fasdf` for just testing proposes to get the app packaged for testing. If I move that file though on my local machine it won't catch the update which is what I'm afraid of. I was thinking that this would need to be a trusted location but I will probably do as you say and set it in a location that I will ensure not to tamper with.